# How to Bypass SSL Certificate Verification in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, ssl, ssl-certificate, flutter-dependencies

How to Bypass SSL Certificate Verification in flutter?

> Error: Handshake Exception: Handshake error in client(OS Error:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED:self signed certificate(handshake.cc:345)

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54285172/how-to-solve-flutter-certificate-verify-failed-error-while-performing-a-post-req

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you are using a self signed certificate, which is not trusted by the OS. You can set it as trusted following these steps:

Create a class that overrides `HttpOverrides` in the following way:

```scala
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) {
        //add your certificate verification logic here
        return true;
      };
  }
}
```

Then, in your main method, instance your class and set it as the global HttpOverride:

```dart
HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
```

If `badCertificateCallback` returns `true` it will accept all bad certificates; if returns false it will reject a bad certificate.

link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66268556/11738366

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31801004)

Comment: It has a mistake in the code. It has to be `SecurityContext? context`

Answer (score 3):

You need to configure your HttpService to work with Self-Signed SSL local servers. Like this:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';
class HttpService {
  Future<dynamic> sendRequestToServer(dynamic model, String                         reqType, bool isTokenHeader, String token) async {
      HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
      client.badCertificateCallback =((X509Certificate cert, String  host, int port) => true);
      HttpClientRequest request = await         client.postUrl(Uri.parse("https://${serverConstants.serverUrl}$reqType"));
      request.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      if(isTokenHeader){
         request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer $token');
      }
     request.add(utf8.encode(jsonEncode(model)));
     HttpClientResponse result = await request.close();
     if(result.statusCode == 200) {
        return jsonDecode(await result.transform(utf8.decoder)
        .join());
     } else {
        return null;
     }
   }
}
```

Read more from [here](https://medium.com/@sparkooo/flutter-and-self-signed-ssl-rest-791d88882490).

Comment: how can call this function?