# How to disable certificate verification in Java *with Flutter*?

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle, ssl-certificate

On a fresh install of Flutter, JDK, and Android Studio 3.5.3, Flutter always runs into an error when trying to build for an Android app. During the Gradle task "assembleDebug", it runs into an sslHandshakeException. I'm wondering how to disable certificate verification so that it can still run (assume I don't care about the security issues this raises). I believe this needs to go through the Java JDK.

Additional context:

- MacBook Pro running macOS Big Sur 11.4
- Flutter 2.2.3
- `flutter doctor -v` output:

```
% flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on macOS 11.4 20F71 darwin-x64, locale en)
    • Flutter version 2.2.3 at /usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/2.2.3/flutter
    • Framework revision f4abaa0735 (12 days ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
    • Engine revision 241c87ad80
    • Dart version 2.13.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/peternielsen/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-S, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.5.1, Build version 12E507
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 44.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.57.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.24.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    •
      Android 8.1.0 (API 27) (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)                       • chrome        • web-javascript •
      Google Chrome 91.0.4472.114

• No issues found!
```

- Error output from `flutter run`:

```
% flutter run
Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you notice
graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with
"--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
                                                                        
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                
                                                                        
* What went wrong:                                                      
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.                  
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.       
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0.            
     Required by:                                                       
         project :                                                      
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0.         
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.0/gradle-4.1.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.0/gradle-4.1.0.pom'.
               > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
                                                                        
* Try:                                                                  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
                                                                        
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                              
                                                                        
BUILD FAILED in 3s                                                      
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         4.3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I don't know why it's doing the error, I just need a way to disable the SSL Certificate Verification for Flutter.

Note that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64533341/how-to-bypass-ssl-certificate-verification-in-flutter) is similar, however it asks how to disable it within Flutter code that pulls from a server and my problem needs to stop Java from doing it when a Flutter app is run.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
% keytool -importcert -file ~/Downloads/google.cer -alias google -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts
Enter keystore password:  
Re-enter new password: 
Owner: CN=*.google.com
Issuer: CN=Qustodio Protection CA, OU=Qustodio, O=Qustodio LLC, L=Barcelona, ST=Barcelona, C=ES
Serial number: cd639bb2
Valid from: Tue Jun 22 06:37:09 PDT 2021 until: Tue Sep 14 06:37:08 PDT 2021
Certificate fingerprints:
     SHA1: B3:A2:BF:28:62:78:E3:EE:2F:6D:1A:04:C8:3F:83:E2:EA:A8:C0:95
     SHA256: A4:CC:97:CC:FB:2B:67:40:F4:17:EC:D2:78:5D:AA:CB:1F:ED:C8:E7:01:85:3E:8A:9F:09:05:51:2A:25:F0:E4
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 3

Extensions: 

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  serverAuth
]

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: *.google.com
  DNSName: *.appengine.google.com
  DNSName: *.bdn.dev
  DNSName: *.cloud.google.com
  DNSName: *.crowdsource.google.com
  DNSName: *.datacompute.google.com
  DNSName: *.google.ca
  DNSName: *.google.cl
  DNSName: *.google.co.in
  DNSName: *.google.co.jp
  DNSName: *.google.co.uk
  DNSName: *.google.com.ar
  DNSName: *.google.com.au
  DNSName: *.google.com.br
  DNSName: *.google.com.co
  DNSName: *.google.com.mx
  DNSName: *.google.com.tr
  DNSName: *.google.com.vn
  DNSName: *.google.de
  DNSName: *.google.es
  DNSName: *.google.fr
  DNSName: *.google.hu
  DNSName: *.google.it
  DNSName: *.google.nl
  DNSName: *.google.pl
  DNSName: *.google.pt
  DNSName: *.googleadapis.com
  DNSName: *.googleapis.cn
  DNSName: *.googlevideo.com
  DNSName: *.gstatic.cn
  DNSName: *.gstaticcnapps.cn
  DNSName: googlecnapps.cn
  DNSName: *.googlecnapps.cn
  DNSName: gkecnapps.cn
  DNSName: *.gkecnapps.cn
  DNSName: googledownloads.cn
  DNSName: *.googledownloads.cn
  DNSName: recaptcha.net.cn
  DNSName: *.recaptcha.net.cn
  DNSName: widevine.cn
  DNSName: *.widevine.cn
  DNSName: ampproject.org.cn
  DNSName: *.ampproject.org.cn
  DNSName: ampproject.net.cn
  DNSName: *.ampproject.net.cn
  DNSName: google-analytics-cn.com
  DNSName: *.google-analytics-cn.com
  DNSName: googleadservices-cn.com
  DNSName: *.googleadservices-cn.com
  DNSName: googlevads-cn.com
  DNSName: *.googlevads-cn.com
  DNSName: googleapis-cn.com
  DNSName: *.googleapis-cn.com
  DNSName: googleoptimize-cn.com
  DNSName: *.googleoptimize-cn.com
  DNSName: doubleclick-cn.net
  DNSName: *.doubleclick-cn.net
  DNSName: *.fls.doubleclick-cn.net
  DNSName: *.g.doubleclick-cn.net
  DNSName: dartsearch-cn.net
  DNSName: *.dartsearch-cn.net
  DNSName: googletraveladservices-cn.com
  DNSName: *.googletraveladservices-cn.com
  DNSName: googletagservices-cn.com
  DNSName: *.googletagservices-cn.com
  DNSName: googletagmanager-cn.com
  DNSName: *.googletagmanager-cn.com
  DNSName: googlesyndication-cn.com
  DNSName: *.googlesyndication-cn.com
  DNSName: *.safeframe.googlesyndication-cn.com
  DNSName: app-measurement-cn.com
  DNSName: *.app-measurement-cn.com
  DNSName: gvt1-cn.com
  DNSName: *.gvt1-cn.com
  DNSName: gvt2-cn.com
  DNSName: *.gvt2-cn.com
  DNSName: 2mdn-cn.net
  DNSName: *.2mdn-cn.net
  DNSName: googleflights-cn.net
  DNSName: *.googleflights-cn.net
  DNSName: admob-cn.com
  DNSName: *.admob-cn.com
  DNSName: *.gstatic.com
  DNSName: *.metric.gstatic.com
  DNSName: *.gvt1.com
  DNSName: *.gcpcdn.gvt1.com
  DNSName: *.gvt2.com
  DNSName: *.gcp.gvt2.com
  DNSName: *.url.google.com
  DNSName: *.youtube-nocookie.com
  DNSName: *.ytimg.com
  DNSName: android.com
  DNSName: *.android.com
  DNSName: *.flash.android.com
  DNSName: g.cn
  DNSName: *.g.cn
  DNSName: g.co
  DNSName: *.g.co
  DNSName: goo.gl
  DNSName: www.goo.gl
  DNSName: google-analytics.com
  DNSName: *.google-analytics.com
  DNSName: google.com
  DNSName: googlecommerce.com
  DNSName: *.googlecommerce.com
  DNSName: ggpht.cn
  DNSName: *.ggpht.cn
  DNSName: urchin.com
  DNSName: *.urchin.com
  DNSName: youtu.be
  DNSName: youtube.com
  DNSName: *.youtube.com
  DNSName: youtubeeducation.com
  DNSName: *.youtubeeducation.com
  DNSName: youtubekids.com
  DNSName: *.youtubekids.com
  DNSName: yt.be
  DNSName: *.yt.be
  DNSName: android.clients.google.com
  DNSName: developer.android.google.cn
  DNSName: developers.android.google.cn
  DNSName: source.android.google.cn
]

Trust this certificate? [no]:  yes
Certificate was added to keystore
keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /jre/lib/security/cacerts (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Did you try to open that link in a browser?
`https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.0/gradle-4.1.0.pom`

Comment: Yes, it automatically downloads the file (which is 6KB) but I have no idea where I could put it.

Comment: you should put the correct certificates in the Java folder. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36427118/7277653

Comment: I can't find the correct certificates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to `https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.0/` in your browser:

- firefox -  click on HTTPS certificate chain (the lock icon right next to URL address). Click `"more info" > "security" > "show certificate" > "details" > "export.."`. Pickup the name and choose file type example.cer
- chrome - click on site icon left to address in address bar, select "Certificate" -> "Details" -> "Export" and save in format "Der-encoded binary, single certificate".

2. Now you have file with keystore and you have to add it to your JVM. Determine location of cacerts files, eg.
   `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts`
3. Next import the `example.cer` file into cacerts in command line (may need administrator command prompt):

`keytool -importcert -file example.cer -alias example -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts`

enter PW: changeit (Can be changeme on Mac)

Restart your JVM/PC.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ)

Comment: I'm on mac... I can't figure out how to get the certificate.

Comment: @PeterNielsen if you have only Safari then try this https://www.markbrilman.nl/2012/03/howto-save-a-certificate-via-safari-on-mac/

Comment: I downloaded the certificate, but the command did not work.

Comment: I've updated the post with error output from the command.

Comment: you should check if you have the environmental variable `JAVA_HOME` - run `echo $JAVA_HOME`. If you don't have then you should either set it or figure out the right path to the cert dir and use it in the command.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842743/how-to-set-java-home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x-10-9

Comment: I ran the command and restarted, and the output is the same with the error.

Comment: Might you have several JDK installed?

Comment: No, just one. ```% java --version
java 16.0.1 2021-04-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16.0.1+9-24)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0.1+9-24, mixed mode, sharing)```