# How to add badCertificateCallback to the http.BaseClient [Flutter, Dart]

Tags: flutter, dart, signalr

I am connecting to signalr using signalr_core.
I created the code as below and there is no problem with this connection.

```dart
  SignalRNotification() {
    if (this._hubConnection == null) {
      var options =
          IOClient(HttpClient()..badCertificateCallback = (x, y, z) => true);
      this._hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder()
          .withUrl(serverUrl, options)
          .withAutomaticReconnect()
          .build();
    }

    this._initHub();
  }
```

I want to modify the header information in options.

I added a header referring to [this article.](https://github.com/jamiewest/signalr_core/issues/39) However, a CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error occurs.

```
E/flutter ( 2902): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: 
E/flutter ( 2902):  CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(handshake.cc:354))
```

Here is my code.

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/io_client.dart';
import 'package:signalr_core/signalr_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import '../resources/common.dart';

class _HttpClient extends http.BaseClient {
  final _httpClient = http.Client();

  final Map<String, String> defaultHeaders;

  _HttpClient({@required this.defaultHeaders});

  @override
  Future<http.StreamedResponse> send(http.BaseRequest request) {
    request.headers.addAll(defaultHeaders);
    return _httpClient.send(request);
  }
}

class SignalRNotification {
  static String serverUrl = SignalRURL;
  HubConnection _hubConnection;
  NotificationManager notificationManager = NotificationManager();
  final httpClient = _HttpClient(defaultHeaders: {
    "X-Api-Key": "key",
    "X-Client-Id": "id",
  });

  SignalRNotification() {
    if (this._hubConnection == null) {
      this._hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder()
          .withUrl(serverUrl, HttpConnectionOptions(client: httpClient))
          .withAutomaticReconnect()
          .build();
    }

    this._initHub();
  }
```

I think this problem occurs because there is no badCertificateCallback in the _HttpClient

I also referred to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59622087/flutter-https-with-self-signed-certificate/66268556#66268556), but it didn't work.
I want to know the solution.

Comment: It's impossible 'class _HttpClient extends http.BaseClient...' Can you give me a specific example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpClient` from `dart:io` (which I will refer to as `io.HttpClient`) provides a [`badCertificateCallback` setter](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/HttpClient/badCertificateCallback.html) but `package:http`'s `BaseClient` does not.

However, `package:http` provides several implementations for its `BaseClient` class.  One of them is [`IOClient`](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/io_client/IOClient-class.html) (which I will refer to as `http.IOClient`) which is backed by an `io.HttpClient`.

You therefore should be able to use an `http.IOClient` with an `io.HttpClient` that is configured the way you want, something like:

```dart
import 'dart:io' as io;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:http/io_client.dart' as http;

class _HttpClient extends http.BaseClient {
  final io.HttpClient _ioHttpClient;
  final http.IOClient _httpClient;

  final Map<String, String> defaultHeaders;

  _HttpClient({@required this.defaultHeaders})
     : _ioHttpClient = io.HttpClient() {
    _httpClient = http.IOClient(_ioHttpClient);
  }

  void set badCertificateCallback(BadCertificateCallback callback) =>
    _ioHttpClient.badCertificateCallback = callback;

  @override
  Future<http.StreamedResponse> send(http.BaseRequest request) {
    request.headers.addAll(defaultHeaders);
    return _httpClient.send(request);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this code is complete. An error has occurred in the IDE. 

for example : Undefined class 'http.IOClient' ,
All final variables must be initialized, but '_httpClient' isn't., 
The function 'IOClient' isn't defined.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot an `import`.  It's an untested example; the point is to demonstrate the approach to point you in the right direction, not necessarily to give you an exact implementation.