# Flutter https exception CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: invalid or inconsistent certificate extension(handshake.cc:359))

Tags: flutter, dart, https

I'm getting this error in a flutter app when making https calls with any of the dart:io, http, and dio package clients to a development server that has a self-signed certificate:

> I/flutter ( 5545): HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error:
> I/flutter ( 5545):  CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: invalid or inconsistent certificate extension(handshake.cc:359))

I've tried the suggestions in this post [Flutter https with self signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59622087/flutter-https-with-self-signed-certificate/69547601#69547601) but both setting the badCertificateCallback on the client and using the HttpOverrides.global is not helping, in my case the callback is never hit/called. Any suggestions on what to try next?

Comment: Please check this link this may help you : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23045

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I think the consensus there is to use badCertificateCallback which isn't called in my case. I don't have any control over the server's certificate but I'd like to simply ignore it.